# Default value selected in bootstrap button after logging out of app at login page

Tags: laravel, button, laravel-5.4

I want in my login form that when I logout of the app and redirect to login form page again, I want the office auto selected by default which i choose at the last time when logged in.

I am having the following button code in laravel login.blade.php

```
            <input type="hidden" name="office_id" class="office_id" value="0">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default office_name">Select Office</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                @foreach($offices as $office)
                    <li><a href="#" id="{{$office->id}}">{{$office->name}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
```

These are the login and logout functions which I am using in loginController.php

```
public function login(Request    $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'office_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($user = User::where('email', $request->email)->get()->first()){
        $office = Employee::with('office')->findOrFail($user->id);
        $office_id = $office['office'][0]['id'];
        if($request->office_id == $office_id){
            if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)){
                return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard', compact('office_id')));
            }
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors(['Incorrect Password', 'The Message']);
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors(['Select your office to log in', 'The Message']);
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors(['Invalid Email', 'The Message']);
}

public function adminLogout(){
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    return redirect(route('admin.login'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could achieve this with cookies. You set the time they stay active unlike the session. 
Laravel has a cookie interface-

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#cookies

Cookies using PHP-

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php